# Switch pandas data frame to dictionary

Tags: python

I have a `pandas` data frame of the following shape:

> MNK           Monkey 
> CT            Cat 
> GNNPG Guinnea Pig

And I want to switch it into such dictionary:

> {'MNK':'Monkey','CT':'Cat','GNNPG':'Guinnea Pig'}

Is there a way of doing such transformation (without iterating on rows) ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html?highlight=to_dict#pandas.DataFrame.to_dict)

Comment: `.to_dict()` ...

Comment: Maybe what you want is to combine this two column, and you can use @Palinuro's answer, which can be optimized to `dict(zip(df.code, df.animal))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling your DataFrame as `df` and columns `code` and `animal, you can declare a dictionary iterating over it. That is:

```
your_dict = {c: a for c, a in zip(df.code, df.animal)}
```